# Problem with stateful lambda - Microsoft Compiler Version 19.16.27024.1

Tags: c++, lambda, compiler-bug

Hi I have problem with stateful lambda expression.

This is dummy example, but it seems to me that ms compiler is doing something wrong, or maybe I have some undefined behavior?

code:

```
int main() {

    auto start = [x = 1, z = 1]() mutable {
        goto resume;
        for (; ; ++z) {
            for (x = 1; x < z; ++x) {
            resume:
                std::cout << z;
                if (z > 3)
                    return 1;
            }
        }
    };

    start();
}
```

Microsoft Compiler Version 19.16.27024.1

cl -O2 /std:c++17 (or -O1, -Ox) -----> prints '1' and then infinite number of '2' (wrong I think)

cl -Od /std:c++17 -----> prints 12334

g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0

g++ -03 -----> prints 12334

clang version 8.0.0 (trunk)
clang++ -O3 -----> prints 12334

https://godbolt.org/z/wsHYA- (code but without std::cout)

After removing for loop (this one with x variable) problem is no longer visible;
If somone want to know why I wrote code like this - I want to imitate the behavior of coroutines etc. (nothing serious, for example sequences generators)

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with 19.15.26730 as well.  Looks like some sort of optimization bug.

Comment: `goto` should really be deprecated. Why do you use it anyways?

Comment: did you read this post(I just explained it)? IMO goto is a tool like any other

Comment: @ALX23z `goto` is a tool. It's not one you should reach for often, but it exists and has its uses. I wrote some code a few years ago that was just 5-6 elegant lines but that performed like crap. A few unrolled loops and a couple of `goto`s later, the code looked like shit, but it performed orders of magnitude better. Sometimes you just have to accept that simple shit works ;)

Comment: @Jesper Juhl ever heard of wisdom teeth? They are teeth they grow in mid twenties. Use them. You don't really need them? But they are teeth they can chew. What you get ill and they grow weird? And they are useless? But you have extra teeth. No? Sorry no. Some old tools and methods are here in C++ for historical reasons and should not be used these days, some tools are written badly in C++ and std and are almost impossible to change due to standarts and backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

It's an optimization bug, and seems to be related to inlining the call to start, as the non-inlined lambda does not appear to be buggy.

A workaround for this particular case is to replace the inner for loop and goto with a do/while loop:

```
    auto start = [x = 1, z = 1]() mutable {
        for (;; ++z) {
            do {
                std::cout << z;
                if (z > 3)
                    return 1;
            } while (++x < z);
            x = 1;
        }
    };
```

Comment: This particular case is just dummy example, anyway you will stuck at z = 4 and x = 1, goto is crucial here, I asked this question not to find workaround in this particular case but to understand what is the problem. Anyway thx for help :)

Comment: @KrzysztofSommerfeld This code does exactly what your original code does.  What's the problem you see with it?

Comment: In this simple example it is ( I could argue about replacing do while with while) but its just bug trigger. Imagine more complicated loop and goto solution is just simpler.